# Will I lose privileges if I offer a bonus and my points drop below the requirement?

Tags: support, bounty, reputation

I am curious. I have 1,830 points and expect to soon have 2,000 and moderator privileges.

If I have 2,001 points and obtain moderator privileges and then offer and award a bonus of 100 points, leaving me with 1,901 points, will I lose my privileges?

Moderate? I'm afraid I can't do that, Dave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - privileged are calculated based on your *current* reputation, and reputation lost in offering bounties is counted. You would lose the 2k privilege any time your reputation drops below 2000.

You may be interested in these threads on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [Is losing privileges after placing bounty OK?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/is-losing-privileges-after-placing-bounty-ok)
- [Exclude bounties from affecting privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42834/exclude-bounties-from-affecting-privileges)
- [Notify user when setting a bounty will revoke a privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11930/notify-user-when-setting-a-bounty-will-revoke-a-privilege)

Comment: I suspected as much. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: SE policy at its finest.